# How to read method name from soap using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Team, could anyone help me how to get method name out of SOAP response from Server using javascript/jQuery. Note that method name is not fixed one. It varies for each notification from the server. Accordingly i have to call the method at the client side. I don't want to use any library other than jQuery.

eg)

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <m:ActivatedForResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.velu.com">
          <resultCode>0</resultCode>
       </m:ActivatedForResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Question-2** 
I just tried the below if I know my method name (title). But in real case I don't know the method name. And it is not working if I replace "tittle" with "m:tittle"? Anything i am wrong here?

```
var xml = "<rss><channel><title>MyTitle</title></channel></rss>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "title" );

// Please note that i don't want the text; 
// i want to load "title" element itself when it is declared as "m:title" in xml.
alert($title.text());
```

### Solution

```
function Test(){
    xml=loadXMLText("config.xml");
    var $xmlDoc = $(xml),
    $bodyNode = $xmlDoc .find("SOAP-ENV\\:Body");

    $bodyNode.each(function(){ //Iterate mutiple body in different envelope
        $(this).children().each(function(){ //Iterate mutiple remote methods inside the body
            alert($(this).get(0).tagName); // Remote method name
            $(this).children().each(function(){
                alert($(this).prop("tagName")); //attribute name
                alert($(this).text());          //attribute value
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: jQuery *is* a library???

Comment: @Bergi :) Other than jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sollution that's pure VanillaJS: (the fiddle is a little different, in that it doesn't accept a callback function, use the code from [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/imoqix/1/) if you want to pass a function to the parser, too)

```
var parseXML = (function(w,undefined)
{//create parser
    'use strict';
    var parser,i,ie,parsed;
    ie = false;
    switch (true)
    {
        case w.DOMParser !== undefined:
            parser = new w.DOMParser();
        break;
        case new w.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") !== undefined:
            parser = new w.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            parser.async = false;
            ie = true;
        break;
        default :
            throw new Error('No parser found');
    }
    return function(xmlString,getTags, optionalCallback)
    {
        var tags,keep = [];
        if (ie === true)
        {
            parser.loadXML(xmlString);
            parsed = parser;
        }
        else
        {
            parsed = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
        }
        tags = parsed.getElementsByTagNameNS('',getTags);
        for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
        {
            if (opionalCallback)
            {
                keep.push(optionalCallback(tags[i]));
            }
            else
            {
                keep.push(tags[i].textContent);
            }
        }
        //keep.push(parsed);//last element of array is the full DOM
        return keep;
    };
})(this);
var parseResult = parseXML('<rss><channel><m:title>MyTitle</m:title></channel></rss>','title');
var withCB = parseXML('<rss><channel><m:title>MyTitle</m:title></channel></rss>','title',function(node)
    {
        return node.tagName.toLowerCase() + ' => ' + node.textContent.trim();
    });
console.log(parseResult[0]);//logs "My Title"
console.log(withCB[0]);//logs "title => My Title"
```

[A working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zDv3m/). It's based on an XML parser I wrote for another question here a while back [Here's that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6cgf/), to show you how you can change the code to best suite your needs.
All you have to do to make the code with `m:title` is change `getElementsByTagName(tagNames)` to `getElementsByTagNameNS('', tagNames);` and you're there.

To expand a bit on my latest comment:

```
var soapAPI= (function()
{
    var parseXML = (function(){}()),//code from above
    api = {},
    update = function(xml)
    {
        var i, parsed = parseXML(xml, '*',function(node)
        {//change this function to scan for methodName tags in your XML
            return {tag: node.tagName.toLowerCase(),
                    val: node.textContent};
        });
        for(i=0;i<parsed.length;i++)
        {
            api[parsed[i].tag] = parsed[i].val;
        }
        return api;
    };
    api.update = update;
    return api;
}());
```

Basic usage:

```
soapAPI.update(xmlString);//where XML contains method names you're after
console.log(soapAPI);
```

the `soapAPI` object now contains the `update` method, which we defined and a lot of key => value pairs that reflect the SOAP api, for example: `title: getTitleMethodName`.

To optimize this further you could rewrite the update function like so:

```
    update = (function()
    {
        var callback = function(node)
        {//declare callback only once, here
            return {node.tagName.toLowerCase(): node.textContent};
        };
        return function(xml)
        {
            var i, parsed = parseXML(xml, '*',callback);
            for(i=0;i<parsed.length;i++)
            {
                api[parsed[i].tag] = parsed[i].val;
            }
            return api;//<-- this is just for fluent interface
        };
   };
```

Comment: Thanks. But i don't want to read the content of "title"; I want to find out the "title" itself when the xml is like <m:title>.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: [This'll do just that](http://jsbin.com/imoqix/2/), merely change `getElementsByTagName` to `getElementsByTagNameNS('', tagName);` and you're done

Comment: +1. Thank you! Elias, but tagName is not fixed to search. it varies from each response from the server. Now what should i do ?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: Well, that's just where my code comes in: `parseXML(response, 'tagToSearch');`: the second parameter you're passing is the tag that will be searched. So if the one time you want to search for `title`, simply call `parseXML(xmlString, 'title');` whereas, if you want to search for a `quote` tag, the next time, you simply call `parseXML(xmlString, 'quote');`. By default, the code above will return the textContent, if you want to return something else: `simpleXML(xmlString, 'p',function(elem){ elem.tagName().toLowerCase()});` the function you pass will be applied to elems found

Comment: The way the `parseXML` function is written is so that you'll only create one parser object, which is re-used on each call to `parseXML`. This makes the code somewhat more complicated to grasp at first, but what you should be looking at is the `retrun function(xmlString,tagName,optionalCallback)` line, because that's the code that actually parses and searches the xmlString

Comment: Not sure if I quite follow you, but if the XML string contains ~20 tags, of which you need the value, then `parseXML(string, 'response')` will return an array of ~20 strings, each of them representing one distinct tag. If, however, you're calling a service ~20 times, then you'll have to call this function ~20 times. But there's just no way around that

Comment: ooohhh sorry! I am not talking about no of tags. even in SOAP only one <m:methodName> is possible. What i mean is 20 different function/method() declared at client side. If any one method(RMI) soap notification comes to the Client, then i have use this search API with all the 20 function names to findout which method i should call. But if i have reflection/some api in javascript gives me a direct method name; i will directly invoke that method.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar: Then just create a module, that can update, and uses this code to build an object that maps all API calls. I'll clarify this in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/BsrTR/

```
var $xml = $("<rss><channel><m:title>MyTitle</m:title></channel></rss>"),
    $title = $xml.find("m\\:title");
```

Tested on chrome, ie and ff.

**EDIT**

```
var xml = "<rss><channel><title>MyTitle</title></channel></rss>",
$xml = $( xml ),
$title = $xml.find( "title" );
alert($title.text());
```

Comment: Thanks!. I tried but it is not working. Curious is there any  difference between your code and the below? var xml = "<rss><channel><m:title>MyTitle</m:title></channel></rss>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "m\\:title" );
alert($title.text());

Comment: Yes. Your code is different. I don't use `parseXML` method, but I create jquery object initialized with xml string. See my edit.

Comment: +1 Thanks Matty; your first answer resolves : issue. But two things 1) Actually i don't know the method name to find. This is what i have to find out, since server sends lot of soap xml to perform remote method invocation.  2) If you give more explanation on the difference between parseXML and direct parsing; will help more like me (newbie)

Comment: You mean you don't know xml node name to find?

Answer (score 0):

This will return the title element in the xml string you have shown us...

```
var $title = $(xml).find("title");
```

You would use `text()` as you have in your example to get the actual text value.